# Nautilus not responding when open through terminal Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, filesystem

When I open directory using command line

```
#User: nautilus ./ #command for opening dic
```

This command works perfectly and specified directory is open but when i close the directory and press ctrl + z in terminal all other directories shutdown/close and error message show "Files not responding" and the Files not open again. If anyone have solution about this issue.